# Not able to sign in with Google using WebKit webview

Tags: c, gtk, webkit, webkitgtk

I created a small "browser" with the sole purpose of doing web auth using Google sign for my application. For that, I'm using webkitgtk using c.

If I send that request in a regular full-fledged browser (Chrome, Firefox, Vivaldi, Epiphany) it opens a new window/tab after I click on the **Sign-In with Google** button but on my webview it doesn't do anything.

My WebKit web view settings:

```
webkit_settings_set_javascript_can_open_windows_automatically(settings, TRUE);
webkit_settings_set_allow_modal_dialogs(settings, TRUE);                     
webkit_settings_set_enable_developer_extras(settings, TRUE);                 
webkit_settings_set_enable_site_specific_quirks(settings, TRUE);
```

I'm also capturing the `decide-policy` signal but nothing gets there when I click the button.

```
g_signal_connect(webview, "decide-policy", G_CALLBACK(decide_callback), NULL);
```